# The "Build" tab missing from project properties in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, project-properties

When I open any C# Win-Forms or WPF project in Visual Studio 2013, the "Build" tab doesn't show up. It is visible if I open the project in VS2010. I haven't been able to find any information about this specific tab disappearing.

I've have tried resetting the user settings in vs2013, running the setup repair, and even completely uninstalling and reinstalling vs2013.

Any ideas on how to get it back?

Comment: We had this happen to a few people and disabling post sharp extension brought them back. I have version 4.1.11 and dont have this problem, the ones who did had 4.1.14. We are trying to get the older version to see if this fixes it.

Comment: I have that same version of post sharp also. Disabling it fixed the issue for me too. Thanks! Wish I could flag your comment as the "solution".

Comment: @StingyJack I also had this issue and disabling PostSharp fixed it. Thanks. Post it as answer so that I can upvote it.

Comment: Please, what exact version and edition of Visual Studio are you using (which update)?

Comment: Do you use CodeRush?

Comment: It is a bug and it is going to be fixed in 4.1.15 version soon. More details here: http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/2707-c-project-properties-build-and-debug-options-disappear-after-installing-postsharp-4114

Answer (score 5):

The issue is now fixed with the Version 4.1.15, which you can download [here](https://www.postsharp.net/downloads/postsharp-4.1/v4.1.15).

**Changes in the 4.1 branch**

```
4.1.15 2015-06-09 Bug 11560 VSiX: missing Build and Debug pages 
in project properties.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in Visual Studio 2012 and I can confirm, that this issue is based on Post Sharp.

After updating PostSharp to Version 4.1.14 the "Build" and the "Postsharp" Tab disapears.
Uninstalling PostSharp fixed this issue. The "Build" Tab is back again.

Comment: It is a bug releated to 4.1.14 version only. It will be fixed in the next version and 4.1.13 is not affected at all.

Comment: I had this issue too in VS2013, and disabling PS extension fixed it.